# Webpage not publicly accessible via port 80

Tags: node.js, server, webserver, portforwarding, koa

I have the following code written with Node/Koa, which is serving to `port 80`:

```
const 
koa = require('koa'),
route = require('koa-route'),
network = koa(),
common = require('koa-common'),
PORT = 80;

// enable logger middleware
network.use(common.logger('dev'));

// enable static middleware
network.use(common.static(__dirname + '/public'));

network.use(route.get('/', index));
network.use(route.get('/about', about));
function *index() {
 this.body = "<h1>Is this message on my computer, or on yours...?</h1>";
}
function *about() {
 this.body = "<h2>How about now...</h2>";
}
var server = network.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

I have reserved an address (`168.192.1.91`) for the host computer, set up port forwarding to this address on `port 80`, made an exception in the Windows 10 firewall for `port 80` when connected to via any protocol, and tested with [You Get Signal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/):

[image: Port Forwarding Tester]

which confirms that the port is currently open. When I browse to `localhost:80` I can see the default page. However, when I type the computer's public IP address into the browser (I'm typing in the one that I've partially obscured, which I believe should be the correct one):

[image: IP Address]

this page fails to load with the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached

109.[...] took too long to respond.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

and there is no activity in the Koa log (which logs fine when I browse to there via `localhost:80`). Any ideas what could be blocking the connection?

I have also tried adding the host address as a second parameter like this:

```
const HOST = "127.0.0.1";

    var server = network.listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

This works for the loopback address, but when I specify my public IP I get this error:

```
C:\Sites\order-server>node --harmony cheese.js
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL [My public IP here]:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at net.js:1379:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:386:13)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:407:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

Comment: Did you also open up the port in your router?

Comment: @BubbleHacker I set up port forwarding. Is that not the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe koa by default only binds to 127.0.0.1 so you can try binding to any host explicitly with `.listen(80, '0.0.0.0')`

Otherwise if the firewall ant the port forwarding is configured accordingly, the problem could be that your Internet Provider is blocking incoming connections somewhere. You could try useing an Port over 1024, if it only blocks Ports below.

Comment: Ah. I think you might be right Julian. I was wondering if I needed to change the IP address it serves to but I couldn't find out how in any of the docs. I could just use express I suppose but I think I'd rather Koa because I like how it's all modular. I need to sleep now but tomorrow I'll probably just trying adding the IP address as a second parameter the way you do with express tomorrow and see if that works. If it does I'll accept your answer :).

Comment: Ok, I ended up trying it before going to bed but it does work :(. Have added the error message I get to the question.

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to specify the computer IP not the public IP and then the port forwarding handled the rest. All working now.

Comment: Thats right, bacause in your local network you comunicate with a private IP and the Router changes this IP to the public one (NAT).